# Actiontec v1000h wireless router connection stupiditiy

Tags: router, connection, wireless-networking

Recently my house got a new Actiontec v1000h router from Telus. Everyone else seems to have no problem connecting to the wireless, but I simply cannot. I attemp to connect, type in the password accuratly, and it comes up with a "Windows was unable to connect to network" error message. It tells me to try restarting the router, which does not help, then tells me nothing else. I CAN however get on with ethernet connection. My MAC address is not blocked, I checked. A friend of mine also got one of these routers, and I cannot connect to it either, so it must be something on my end. HAAALP

Comment: You need to edit your question and include much more information about the PC that has issues connecting to this model of router, since you already ruled out a possible router issue it must be the PC, which we know nothing about by reading your question.

Comment: What's the wireless setup on the router using for authorization/encryption (ie: WPA2)? Does your computer's Wifi adapter support what it's using?